# How to call POST RESTFUL service thru Console application

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, post, console

I have a rest ful service (POST) which accepts Json object as an input (Request body in Fiddler). Now I wanted to consume the service from Console Applciation with dynamic values (either read from text file or hardcoded values). I will log the actions like, for this test data XXXXX, the service returns values.

Can any one help me how to automate this process. I wold like to comsume this service from Console application.

Pls note Output also JSON string.

Any suggestion will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make the POST request, something like:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
var enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
var data = enc.GetBytes(serializedJson);

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var sr = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    sr.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var res = req.GetResponse();
var res= new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

You can easily create the `serializedJson` from an object like:

```
var serializedJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDataObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the following web api package from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) in your console project

Add a reference to System.Net.Http and System.Runtime.Serialization

Create a contract class of the data you want to send and receive (the same as in your webservice)

```
[DataContract]
public class YourObject{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

In your console app call the webservice like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<YourObject>("http://yourserviceurl:port/controller", objectToPost).Result;
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}else{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
```

More info about webapi [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22#documentation)