# How to test wcf service method that takes input as stream from REST client tool

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I am creating wcf service that accepts stream as a input parameter.

Here is my method in Contract

```
 [OperationContract(Name = "PostSampleMethod")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         UriTemplate = "PostSampleMethod")]

        string PostSampleMethod(Stream data);
```

And here is the implementation of it

```
 public string PostSampleMethod(Stream data)
        {
            // convert Stream Data to StreamReader
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            // Read StreamReader data as string
            string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string returnValue = xmlString;
            // return the XMLString data
            return returnValue;
        }
```

I am using ARC or Boomerang tool to test my service's method. My problem is  what input data or in what format I need to send from REST client tool to test this method.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can check the below url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569078/how-to-call-post-restful-service-thru-console-application

Answer (score 1):

Since you read the incoming stream as string(*by using StreamReader*), you can send any string(xml, json, free format) to your server.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent("aaaa");
var resp = await client.PostAsync("http://....../PostSampleMethod", content);
var status = resp.StatusCode;
var retValue = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but as I mentioned that I am using advanced rest client as a tool to test my services not the console application.

Comment: @user2750155 It is just a sample. As I said in the answer *you can send any string(xml, json, free format) to your server.*